# Difference in $\mathscr{L}^1(\mu)$ and $\mathscr{L}^1(\mu^\nu)$

Tags: measure-theory

Can someone give me an example that indicates the difference between $\mathscr{L}^1(\mu)$ and $\mathscr{L}^1(\mu^\nu)$, with $\mu^\nu$ indicating the measure's completion.

We have seen that $L^1(\mu)$ and $L^1(\mu^\nu)$ are the same, but I am struggling finding an example where this was not the same if we don't have an equivalence relation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any set $M$ of finite measure which is measurable with respect to the completed sigma algebra, but not with respect to the original one. Then $\chi_M$ (the indicator function of $M$ is in $\mathscr{L}^1(\mu^\nu)$, but not in the other $\mathscr{L}^1$ space.

You can also take $M$ as a (nonmeasurable with respect to $\mu$) subset of a $\mu$ null set.

Since the equivalence class spaces coincide, we know that for each $f\in \mathscr{L}^1(\mu^\nu)$, there is a $g\in \mathscr{L}^1(\mu)$ with $f=g$ almost everywhere. Thus, the above example is more or less typical.